# How do I remove Java Web Start.app - 15.0.1 from a Mac OSX system?

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I am looking for a way to effectively remove Java Web Start from several Mac OSX systems. I've found some conflicting information on how exactly to do this so I am looking for clarification on the subject.

More specifically if a terminal command can take care of this great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the follow terminal commands is the solution to totally removing Java.

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```